# Find the number of roots of the equation in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

How many roots does the equation $$\\x^{x^x}=(x^x)^x\\$$ have in $\\\mathbb{R}$?

My observations:I observed that $x=-1,1,2$ are its roots.

Are there other roots of this equation?And how we can find them?

Thanks.

Comment: $(x^x)^x$ is just equal to $x^{x^2}$.

Comment: Yes you are right then what we can do?

Comment: If $x>0$ then $x=1$ or $x=2$. Take logarithm both sides and assume $x\neq 1$, then we get $x^2=x^x$. What is the solution of this equation which is not equal to $x=1$?

Comment: $x=2$ is then the solution other than $x=1$ of the equation $x^2=x$

Comment: Finding non-positive (or, complex) root of this equation seems quite difficult. Complex exponent for arbitrary complex number is not even uniquely determined.

Comment: I need only real solutions

Comment: Do note that $x = -1$ is not a root of the original equation.

Comment: If $x$ is negative, $x^{x^x}$ is not a real number unless $x$ is odd integer. If $n\le-3$ is an odd integer then $|n^{n^2}|>1$ but $|n^{n^n}|<1$.

Comment: $-1^{-1^{-1}}=-1$ and $(-1^{-1})^{-1}=-1$

Comment: This is $x^y = y^x$ with the constraint $y = x^x$.

Comment: Am I stupid or every $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for which $x^{x^x}$ is defined is a solution? For $x^{x^x}=(x^x)^x$.

Comment: @Martigan $3^{3^3}=3^{27}$ but $(3^3)^3=3^9$

Comment: I am stupid! ;-), but your example is not accurate...

Comment: According to Mathematica, using Reduce[], the solutions in $\mathbb{R}$, are -1, 1, and 2 as originally stated.

Answer (score 7):

$$x^{x^x}=(x^x)^x$$
$$x^{x^x}=x^{x^2}$$

Taking logarithm on both sides,

$${x^x}\,log\, \left\lvert x \right\rvert={x^2}\,log\, \left\lvert x \right\rvert$$

$$({x^x}-{x^2})\,log\,\left\lvert x \right\rvert=0$$

Considering $log\, \left\lvert x \right\rvert=0$, we get
$$x=\pm\,1$$

Considering $${x^x}-{x^2}=0$$

$${x^x}={x^2}$$

Taking logarithm on both sides,

$$x\,log\,\left\lvert x \right\rvert=2\,log\,\left\lvert x \right\rvert$$

$$(x-2)\,log\,\left\lvert x \right\rvert=0$$

Therefore,
$$x\,=-1\,,\,1,\,2$$

Answer (score 5):

You have them all.  If $x \lt 0$, $x^x$ is only defined for $x$ integral.  If $x$ is integral and less than $-1$, $x^x$ is not integral and $x^{x^x}$ is not defined.  Similarly neither side is defined for $x=0$. The only solution less than or equal to zero is $-1$.

For $x \gt 0$, we can write this as $x^{(x^x)}=x^{(x^2)}$  and take natural logs to give $x^x \ln x = x^2 \ln x$.  Since $\ln x \neq 0$ unless $x=1$, we can check that case, finding it is a solution, then exclude it and divide by it. This gives $x^x=x^2, x \gt 0 ,x \neq 1$  Taking another log gives $x=2$ as the only remaining solution.

Answer (score 1):

For $ x^{x^x} = x^{x^2} $ the three roots are:  1 ( double root), and 2, found by substitution possible Taylor expansion around root and direct graphing.